# Aptana Studio "Content Assist" rebuild for Twitter Bootstrap Stylesheet

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, aptana, aptana3

I have an php project, I'll include "bootstrap" stylesheet from the ".css" file. Aptana Content Assist doesn't work and i cannot get my tags with the autocomplete.

**But this is only in "bootstrap" where it is installed!**

1. The Content Assist working properly in different private format file in different projects.
2. I think, perception is experiencing a shortage of a certain file size.

Is there any solution?

- *Version 3*
- *Build 3.6.0.201407100658*

> Examples are additional  **screenshots**

[image]

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Incredibly frustrating. Have been trying for hours. It seems the theme css files are recognized by Aptana, but the others are not. Let me know if you figure it out.